# How to forward port tun0 to local adress via eth0?

Tags: openvpn

IPTABLES

Me  10.8.0.7 Debian

Linux server cent8
eth0 192.168.88.11
tun0 10.8.0.6

How to connect 10.8.0.6:8888  port forwarding to Local 192.168.88.10:443 machine?

Enable forwarding

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
echo '1' | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding ;
echo '1' | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/forwarding
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

# forward 10.8.0.6:8888 to local 192.168.88.10:443 
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.8.0.6 --dport 8888-j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.88.10:443
#  return
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst 192.168.88.10 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.6:8888

# remove
sudo iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING 2
sudo iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING 2
```

What that not working?

Comment: Is this a complete Netfiler? You've added a single rule into each chain, but remove them as no. 2, which is strange, they must have been no. 1 if this is all you have. Also you permitted traffic in the FORWARD in one direction, but no in the other. Also there could be a routing issue on the 192.168.88.10 — does it have a route towards 10.8.0.6?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to forward only a single port, I would not turn on IP forwarding in the kernel, and not mess with iptables, but rather use a specialized program like [socat](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/getting-started-socat) to do the port forwarding (on the linked page you have an example how to do the port forwarding with `socat`). My favorite port forwarding tool is [tcppm](https://3proxy.ru/doc/man8/tcppm.8.html) from the [3proxy](https://3proxy.ru/) package.

Comment: socat -d -d TCP-LISTEN:888,fork,reuseaddr TCP:ifconfig.me:80


Curl localhost:888

But I have error:


2022/03/08 12:45:12 socat[601400] W ioctl(5, IOCTL_VM_SOCKETS_GET_LOCAL_CID, ...): Inappropriate ioctl for device
2022/03/08 12:45:12 socat[601400] N1405] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2022/03/08 12:45:22 socat[601405] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2022/03/08 12:45:22 socat[601405] N exiting with status 0
2022/03/08 12:45:22 socat[601400] N childdied(): handling signal 17

Can you help me?

Comment: @Low-voltagesystemsengineer  I can't too much, not knowing your system. Many things may be wrong. Did you run this as root? What does the name `Curl` mean in your command? Aren't there too many parameters (basic socat syntax is `socat [options] <address> <address>`, I see more than 2 addresses here)? Is anything already occupying port 888? Is `ifconfig.me:80` available and responding? Try without `,fork,reuseaddr` first - does it work?